# Show record after comparing dates stored as varchar in Database

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have dates stored in the database as `dd/mm/yy`, I want to show records based on dates. I have wrote following code but it is not returning correct results. I think there is some mistake in query.

```
private void FillDataGrid()
{
    con.Open();

    var date1 = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var date2 = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    label4.Content = date1;
    label5.Content = date2;

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select batch_id, product_name, quantity, left_qty, purchaseDate, manufacturing_date, expiryDate from batch where Convert(varchar, expiryDate, 103) BETWEEN '" + date1 + "' AND '" + date2 + "' ", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();   // being used to calculate total price
    sda.Fill(dt);
    sda.Fill(ds);

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        // Binding the Grid with the Itemsource property
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }

    con.Close();
}
```

It is giving wrong results snap is attached [Image of Wrong Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A46SP.jpg)

Comment: (1) Learn to use parameters.  (2) Store dates as `date`, not as strings.  (3) Use date operations, not string operations, on dates.

Comment: Use ISO format for dates YYYYMMDD, e.g. '20180702' for today's date.

Comment: Now it would be so much difficult for me to convert it to Date format as it is used a lot in code. So please suggest some another solution.

Comment: I second all three of the suggestions from @GordonLinoff.

Comment: It isn't going to work as a text comparison.  The whole point of dates is that they handle all the "funny" things, like leap years, months with different numbers of days in them, year boundaries, etc.  if you make it into a pure text comparison then you lose all of that.

Comment: then what should i do now. As it would be not possible for me to change it to Date in Database.

Comment: What date do you have in database ?

Comment: In database Date is stored as Varchar and format is dd/mm/yy.

Comment: Are you saying that `expiryDate` is stored in your database as text, i.e. VARCHAR or NVARCHAR, etc.?  If this is the case then `CONVERT` it back to a `DATE` as you pull it out, then compare it to other dates in ISO format and it should work fine.  You should really look at making the from and to dates into parameters though.

Comment: @RichardHansell yes i am trying to do same thing you said. Please take a look on my sql query. Because it is returning wrong results.

Comment: Have you tried using a delimiter ('#') instead of quotation in your query ?

Comment: @Prany no i have not used delimiter.

Comment: added query with delimiter. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this line:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select batch_id,product_name,quantity,left_qty,purchaseDate,manufacturing_date,expiryDate from batch where Convert(varchar,expiryDate,103) BETWEEN '" + date1 + "' AND '" + date2 + "' ", con);
```

...and turn it into something more like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select batch_id,product_name,quantity,left_qty,purchaseDate,manufacturing_date,expiryDate from batch where Convert(varchar,expiryDate,103) BETWEEN @from AND @to;", con);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWthValue("@from", "'" + Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'");
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWthValue("@to", "'" + Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "'");
```

---

So I quickly spoofed this up on a SQL Sever 2016 database with a Visual Studio 2017 solution.  I had to remove the single quotes to get it to work, which I had an inkling might be the case.  This is the code I actually ended up getting working:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select batch_id, product_name, quantity, left_qty, purchaseDate, manufacturing_date, expiryDate from batch where CONVERT(DATE, expiryDate, 103) BETWEEN @from AND @to;", con);
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker2.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Note that my date time pickers didn't work with `SelectedDate` but you might well be targeting a different version of .NET, etc. so maybe you will need those.  Anyway, the key here is:

- `CONVERT` your text string to a `DATE` using `103` to make it handle the dd/mm/yyyy format;
- parameterise your `from` and `to` dates to avoid SQL injection, etc.;
- Don't add the single quotes `'` as this is all handled nicely for you when you use parameters.

I agree with the other commenters above though; storing dates as text in a database is a disaster waiting to happen.  This should get you going for the short-term, but I would recommend taking a step back and thinking about this in a longer term scenario.

---

Finally, here's an image of it working, and the code behind:

[image: SQLDataAdapterCode]

Comment: What happens when you run a SQL query directly against the database, e.g.: `SELECT * FROM batch WHERE CONVERT(DATE, expiryDate, 103) BETWEEN '20180101' AND '20180702';`  Obviously you would need to play around with those dates (01-01-2018 to 02-07-2018) a little?

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working. I am so much thankful to you.

Comment: Sorry i said that its not working because i missed some statements in it. Now it is working thanks a lot.

Comment: I already had upvoted it, someone else must have downvoted it for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it with help of @Richard Hansel. And now below is working line of Code.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select batch_id,p_name,quantity,left_qty,purchaseDate,manufacturing_date,expiryDate from batch b cross apply (select p_name from products p where p.p_id_pk = b.product_id_fk) products where Convert(DATE,expiryDate,103) BETWEEN @from AND @to", con);
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker1.SelectedDate.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker2.SelectedDate.Value).ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using delimiter (#) like below on query.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select batch_id,product_name,quantity,left_qty,purchaseDate,manufacturing_date,expiryDate from batch where Convert(varchar,expiryDate,103) BETWEEN #" + date1 + "# AND #" + date2 + "# ", con);
```

Comment: That's the style you need to use for **MS Access** - but **NOT** for SQL Server .....

Comment: Agree, it does work in sql as well - you can refer- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: In SQL Server this gives `Incorrect syntax near '#'`